# Python 3d bar chart plot

Tags: python, charts, 3d, bar-chart

I am a new python, I would like plot a 3D bar chart in python like this
[image]

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

for drawing this chart in python you have to install 'numpy' and 'matplotlib' libraries. then to draw chart, you can use a code like following

```js
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import style
import os, sys
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

style.use('ggplot')

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x3 = np.zeros(17)
 
#Starting point coordinate for each company on the y-axis
y3 = np.arange(1,18,1)
z3 = np.zeros(17)
 
#
dx = np.ones(17)
dy = np.ones(17)
dz = [22,13, 0, 11,46, 0, 9,1, 0,24,4, 0, 17, 34,0, 17, 2]

x = np.arange(2, 19, 3)

colors = ['green','b','w',
          'green','b','w',
          'green','b','w',
          'green','b','w',
          'green','b','w',
          'green','b']

rects1 = ax1.bar3d(x3, y3, z3, dx, dy, dz, color=colors, alpha=1)
 

ax1.set_xticks([])

ax1.set_yticks(x)


x_ticks_labels = ['bus','car','bicycle','walking', 'train', 'motorcycle']
proxy_1 = plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="green")
proxy_2 = plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="b")
ax1.set_yticklabels(x_ticks_labels, rotation='30')
ax1.legend([proxy_1,proxy_2],['1960','2010'])

ax1.view_init(elev=1, azim=1)
plt.title("commuter ...")
#Show the plot so you can see what it looks like before saving as a SVG. Save as a svg for better image quality on your website.
plt.show()
```

Comment: U are a genius, it works for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you able to add text values on top too Hatran?